I don’t know what to buy! Again!
A continuation of the series starting from this puzzle.

My roommate told me to buy something again!
“What should I buy?” I asked.
“Churned milk, cashews and flavoured water, all mixed together,” they replied.
“What?” I mumbled quietly.
“Just buy that damming ONE ITEM I ASKED YOU TO, WILL YOU!?!” they shouted back.
I can’t believe how rude my roommate is! But what am I supposed to buy?

I'd go with

 Butternut squash
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butternut_squash

since it meets all requirements:

 Churned milk == butter
 cashews == nut(s)
 flavoured water == squash

 all mixed together in "one item"


Correct! Well done!

I can help you!
Is it...

 butternut squash?

Because...

 churned milk = butter,
 cashew = nut,
 and flavoured water = squash


Correct, but the other answer is accepted because they posted their answer first.
